# What woul be the best solution to push data/notification to AIR application? Server side is PHP

Tags: php, air, push

Designing AIR application which has to have server side push or notification, don't know what is the best implementation of this feature in PHP. Please suggest, because at the moment I not sure if this even exists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Great question I am wandering the same think.

I have done some reasearch on the subject myself.

Hopefully it wil help you.

They are 3 solutions that I have found:

1. Use NGiNX with Node.js and Socket.IO (http://blog.mixu.net/2011/01/04/nginx-php-fpm-and-node-js-install-on-centos-5-5/ and http://blog.mixu.net/2011/08/13/nginx-websockets-ssl-and-socket-io-deployment/)
2. Use the NGiNX HTTP PUSH (COMET) module: http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpPushStreamModule
3. NGiNX + Socket.IO: https://github.com/LearnBoost/socket.io/wiki/Nginx-and-Socket.io

Also about the NGiNX PUSH module. I message the creator and he told me that he will support websockets soon.

If you are going to use PHP in a very intensive way you might want to look at PHP HIPHOP for performance reasons.

I really hope my answer helps you or at least puts you on the right track ;)

Answer (score 1):

I think that as HTTP works in a client request fashion, pushing is not possible.

Maybe you could set a timer and refresh every X seconds, minutes or whatever that fits into your application?

Edit:
Actually a socket approach would be a better solution.

Comment: Can you elaborate more on socket approach?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do real push with AIR you have to go socket. Take a look at smartfox server.

edit : i agree about node, i use it often now.